# Switch root manager from Kingo Root to Superuser

Tags: root-access

I have Kingo Root on my phone, and I am trying to switch to Superuser by ClockWorkMod

any help is appreciated

Answer (score -1):

Uninstall KingRoot/Kingoroot and then flash SuperSU zip. Or just flash SuperSU zip without uninstalling KingRoot/KingoRoot

Comment: The Superuser zip won't install